# Terminal gives indentation error, editor does not

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
   count = 0
   i = 0
   while count < len(newlist):

    if newlist[i] == newlist[i+6] and newlist [i+6] != newlist [i+12]:


        two1.append(newlist[i])
        two1.append(newlist[i+1])
        two1.append(newlist[i+2])
        two1.append(newlist[i+3])


    count=count+1   
    i=i+6



print two1
```

In the terminal, I get:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    count=count+1; i=i+6
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

In the learnpython.org editor, I get no error. Either way, two1 is printing as [], which is not what I want.

Comment: Is your editor set up to treat tabs as spaces?

Comment: I actually have been using the learnpython.org website as an editor. Is there a good (free) editor that treats tabs as spaces?

Comment: Any editor intended for programming will have an option to do so.  I use vim, but that has not so much a learning curve as a learning cliff.  I've heard good things about Sublime Text (on all platforms); other things to try include Notepad++ or just IDLE (the built-in python 'IDE').

Comment: The code that you tried in the terminal is clearly different, given that it uses a semicolon while the code file does not.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mixture of tab characters and spaces in your code (visible by selecting if you edit the post, not in the formatted output). Using tabs for indentation in Python is discouraged, and mixing tabs and spaces is even worse. From [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces):

> Never mix tabs and spaces.
>
> The most popular way of indenting Python is with spaces only. The
>   second-most popular way is with tabs only. Code indented with a
>   mixture of tabs and spaces should be converted to using spaces
>   exclusively. When invoking the Python command line interpreter with
>   the -t option, it issues warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs
>   and spaces. When using -tt these warnings become errors. These options
>   are highly recommended!
>
> For new projects, spaces-only are strongly recommended over tabs. Most
>   editors have features that make this easy to do.

Set up your editor to convert tabs to spaces, and life will be better.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line of code is indented, which is illegal, so the terminal is correct. Are you sure you haven't forgotten to paste a line from your source code?

There obviously is some program logic missing - `newlist` and `two1` aren't defined anywhere, for instance.

Answer (score -1):

Your program can't start on an indent.

About Scope:
http://beastie.cs.ua.edu/cs150/book/index_13.html